# Electromagnetic Field Angular Momentum

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum

It's a well-known fact that the Electromagnetic Field has somewhat of a "intrinsic" angular momentum.

However, I'm struggling to find a clear mathematical description of this fact. I find a lot of exercises and applications of this, but not a pure description of how Electromagnetic Fields carry angular momentum, therefore, I'm struggling to accept this fact. If anyone can point me some references, or show me a development, I'll be grateful.

Comment: I don't know what kind of description you want, so at the risk of answering-in-a-comment, I'll ask if you want something like this: Consider the model of the electromagnetic field by itself, with no charges or currents. This model has rotation symmetry, and its equations of motion (Maxwell's equations) can be expressed in terms of an action principle. As in any other system, those two properties imply the existence of a conserved quantity that we call "angular momentum." (This is the general *definition* of angular momentum.) Is this the kind of description you want?

Comment: Thank you, for your comment. It's indeed a more fundamental description that I wanted. I still have some questions: How could one show that the Lagrangian of a particle in a EM have rotational symmetry, and why the conserved quantity is precisely the angular momentum?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the electromagnetic rotational momentum is a subtle point. In short, there are several mathematically different but physically equivalent descriptions.

The subtlety boils down to the fact that the balance of rotational momentum, expressed by the symmetry of the stress-energy-momentum tensor in general relativity

$$
T^\intercal = T
$$

holds for the *total* stress-energy-momentum tensor, not for any more or less arbitrary division we can make of it. If we divide it into an electromagnetic-field contribution $T_{\text{EM}}$ and a matter (bosonic) contribution $T_{\text{M}}$:

$$T = T_{\text{EM}} + T_{\text{M}}$$

then we have

$$
T_{\text{EM}}^\intercal + T_{\text{M}}^\intercal
=
T_{\text{EM}} + T_{\text{M}}
$$

and this equation can be satisfied for instance by requiring the individual contributions to be symmetric, or by allowing them to be non-symmetric but in such a way that their antisymmetric parts cancel out.

These choices correspond to different constitutive equations that connect the two stress-energy-momentum tensors to the field themselves (Faraday tensor, particle-density tensor) and to the metric. But different constitutive equations may still lead to the same physics.

There's a whole book dedicated to this, which I recommend:

- Hutter, van de Ven, Ursescu: [*Electromagnetic Field Matter Interactions in Thermoelastic Solids and Viscous Fluids*](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-37240-7) (Springer 2006)

and these matters are also discussed in the older

- Penfield, Haus: [*Electrodynamics of Moving Media*](https://archive.org/details/Electrodyn_00_Penf) (MIT 1967)

One more text with a very in-depth discussion is

- Truesdell, Toupin: [*The Classical Field Theories*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-45943-6_2) (Springer 1960), part G.